# Will SharePoint 2010 training courses be helpful to work with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, training

Currently most of the training centres are offering classroom training for SharePoint 2010 only and not for 2013. And since we are going to start our first SharePoint project and we decided to go with SharePoint version 2013.

So my question is **will attending a class room training course for SP 2010 be helpful to implement internal & external web applications using SharePoint 2013**?, or it is better to wait for a while till SP 2013 training courses become available ?. As I am thinking of start reading some online training materials for SP 2013 till an official SP 2013 class room training become available?
Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If these training are business or IT (infrastructure) minded :

All the core concepts you'll gain in training sessions are still valid in SharePoint 2013. By the time you fully understand the concept of farms, web applications, service applications, security, site collection, content types, fields, list, libraries, etc. you'll have a much clear view of what SharePoint is and will only have to understand the delta between 2010 and 2013. SharePoint 2013 UI will be slightly different but is still around the concept of the ribbon & the site action (although it's a little gear now !)

- If these training are targeted to developers (and you'll implement solution in the 2013 way) :

I would wait for official 2013 trainings, as the app model / concept is quite different to farm solutions usually described during them.

In both case, I would heavily recommend relying first on good books (eg : for SharePoint 2013, you know have the Wrox - Beginning SharePoint 2013 book which is well worth the little amount of money invested for end / business users) and then complete specific unclear area by following specialized training sessions.

Edit : and you can get all the nice presentations for the official conference : http://mssharepointconference.com/Pages/default.aspx for a low price (200$ at the time of writing, much less than any training !)

Answer (score 2):

Hey I am also doing the same. I am also new to both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013. But I started with the SharePoint 2013 as I am developing the WebParts in it.

As far as App are consider it is bit confusing for the developers to develop it. The main change in SP2013 is the Apps.

If you have gained proper knowledge of developing Web Application for SharePoint 2010. Then you can develop WebParts, EventReceivers, Workflows etc in SP2013 as they are the same in SP2013. Minor changes require.

But for the App Development you should wait for the Official Training classes.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends. At a whole SharePoint 2013 is very similar to SharePoint 2010. I think you can gain a lot of knowledge about SharePoint development on a course about 2010.

What I would recommend you is to also take a look at the differences between the two versions here: [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx)